# Multiple script blocks in a Vue SFC sharing imported symbol

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, vite

I have a Vue SFC with two `<script>` blocks: one for setup, and one for vue router's `beforeRouteEnter` handler that can't be used in setup. They both may use some of the same imports. When running `npm run dev` it requires each script block to import it independently of the other block, but when running `npm run build` the typescript compiler (or linter) throws an error:

```
src/components/MyComponent.vue:72:8 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'auth'.

import auth from '@/auth'
```

What's the proper approach here to handle this issue?

Comment: This is very specific to your setup and shouldn't happen under normal circumstances, needs to be checked, please, provide a way to reproduce. Btw there's defineOptions and no longer a necessity to use both blocks

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about defineOptions. If you write answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The need to use `script` block in order to provide component options that aren't covered by `script setup` syntax is relatively common case.

Since Vue 3.3, `defineOptions` macro is provided for this purpose:

```
<script setup>
...
defineOptions({
  beforeRouteEnter() { ... }
```